# How can I flush left text in the align environment?

Tags: align

I have the following code:

```
\begin{align*}
m^+\cdot k^+ &= m^+\cdot k+m^+ &\text{by M2}\\
&= m\cdot k+k+m^+ &\text{since $k\in B$}\\
&= m\cdot k+(k+m^+) \\
&= m\cdot k+(k^{+}+m) &\text{by the second result}\\
&= m\cdot k+m+k^+ &\text{commutativity of addition}\\
&= m\cdot k^{+}+k^+ 
\end{align*}
```

but the text is all flushed right, but I would prefer it to be flush left to be closer to the actual equations.

[image]

Is there an easy fix for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
m^+\cdot k^+ &= m^+\cdot k+m^+   &&\text{by M2}\\
             &= m\cdot k+k+m^+   &&\text{since $k\in B$}\\
             &= m\cdot k+(k+m^+) \\
             &= m\cdot k+(k^{+}+m)&& \text{by the second result}\\
             &= m\cdot k+m+k^+    &&\text{commutativity of addition}\\
             &= m\cdot k^{+}+k^+ 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,  but I edited it to look as such, and nothing changed. Also, I'm sure I'm using the amsmath package, so I don't think that is the reason for no difference. I put the new code in my original question.

Comment: @yunone: UUUh, sorry, I totally misread it. Will update it

Comment: perhaps you should clarify that it simply works by using double `&`s.